# Are there methods for capturing transcendentally small terms in perturbation theory?

Tags: integration, asymptotics, mathematical-physics, approximation-theory, perturbation-theory

By "transcendentally small terms" I mean corrections to a perturbation that are smaller than all polynomial orders. They are generally exponential in form. I would have linked to a Wikipedia page, but I can't seem to find the term used very often.

Usually [perturbation theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perturbation_theory) is not concerned with small corrections beyond all orders, but if the leading correction is exponentially suppressed then it (in principle) becomes relevant.

Take, as an elementary example, an integral expression from solid state physics:
$$
n = \int^{\infty}_{0}\frac{g(\epsilon)}{e^{(\epsilon-\mu)\beta}+1}\text{d} \epsilon
$$

which computes electron density.

In the limit as $\beta\rightarrow\infty$, traditional perturbation theory gives us:
$$
n = \int_{0}^{\mu}g(\epsilon)\text{d}\epsilon + \frac{\pi^2}{6}\frac{g'(\mu)}{\beta^2}+O(\beta^{-4})
$$

Under the [Sommerfeld Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_electron_model) in three dimensions, $g(\epsilon)\propto\sqrt\epsilon$, so everything is copacetic. However, in two dimensions, $g(\epsilon)\propto1$, so the terms with explicit $\beta$-dependence go to $0$ exactly.

The leading order terms of the perturbation in 2 dimensions are sub-polynomial. In particular, this integral can be used to estimate how $\mu$ (the electron [chemical potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemical_potential)) varies from its ground-state value, $\epsilon_F$ (the [Fermi Energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_energy)). In three dimensions, a linear approximation (in powers of $\mu-\epsilon_F$) for the integral term is sufficient, but in two dimensions, any polynomial expansion for the integral term implies that $\mu=\epsilon_F$ (i.e. the chemical potential is constant for all values of $\beta$).

However, the two-dimensional integral can be evaluated explicitly and the relationship
$$
\epsilon_F=\mu+\frac{1}{\beta}\ln(1+e^{-\mu\beta})\approx\mu+\frac{e^{-\mu\beta}}{\beta}
$$
is found, which clearly varies from the ground state only by a transcendentally small term.

A natural approach might be to attempt an [asymptotic expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_expansion) that extracts the exponential behavior ahead of time, but it is not obvious to me how that could be done for the specific two dimensional case much less for the general perturbation expansion for generic $g(\epsilon)$.

**Question:** Is there any way to have anticipated and corrected for the failure of the power series expansion to find these transcendentally small terms? Are transcendentally small terms simply invisible to perturbation theory, or if you know they are coming (especially if they are leading order) can you capture them?

Comment: not sure, but you may be interested in WKB theory which is a kind of exponential perturbation theory https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WKB_approximation#An_example . You might also investigate boundary layer theory. Often, exponentials are connected with transitions between different regimes of behavior (i.e. like a boundary layer on a plane wing vs the free flow far from the wing). A good book for both topics is Bender and Orzag "Advanced mathematical methods for physicists". I think if you browse this book, you'll see many perturbative results with exponential dependence

Comment: @kevinkayaks I actually own a copy of Bender and Orszag, and I am familiar with both WKB and boundary layers. If you have more specific guidance about where to look in the book or how to apply those concepts, I'm all ears. As it stands, those methods are usually for differential equations, and I don't see how this problem could be cast in terms of a DE.

Comment: I suspect that, on mathematical grounds, there's no general way to anticipate that the perturbative/"Taylor-Maclaurin" asymptotics for $\varepsilon$ near $0$ do not represent the function. That is, how to know in advance that a function is not _analytic_ at $0$? The finite Taylor-Maclaurin expansion (with remainder...) applies regardless. And applies in vector/function-valued settings, as well. Functions like $e^{-1/x}$ for $x>0$, $0$ otherwise, are smooth everywhere, but the perturbative/Taylor-Maclaurin expansion at $0$ is just $0$. And so on... So, you need a restricted class $g$'s.

Comment: This problem belongs to the field of exponential/hyperasymptotics. In your case, there will be exponentially small contributions (as $\beta \to +\infty$) if there are singularities of $g$ along the positive real line. You may also be interested in Écalle's theory of resurgent functions.

Comment: For your particular problem, if $g(t)$ is analytic at $0$ and for $t>0$, then the complete asymptotic expansion is $$
n \sim \sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{(1 - 2^{ - k} )\zeta (k + 1)g^{(k)} (\mu )}}{{\beta ^{k + 1} }}}  + \sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {( - 1)^k {\rm e}^{ - \beta\mu k} \int_0^\mu  {g(t){\rm e}^{\beta k t } {\rm d}t} } 
$$ as $\beta \to+\infty$. If there is an algebraic singularity at the origin, only the coeffieints of the perturbative expansion are affected.